# Create full width and height box inside ScrollView with React Native

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

How can I, in React Native, make a simple ScrollView with black background in which I have a white box with 20px margin around the box?

[image]

I have tried

```
<ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#000', flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, margin: 20, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}
    <Text>Text</Text>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```

but it doesn't fill up the full width and height of the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You should use padding in `ScrollView` like this:

```
<ScrollView style={{ backgroundColor: '#000', flex: 1, padding: 20}}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff' }}>
    <Text>Text</Text>
  </View>
</ScrollView>
```